# Can't connect to MariaDB by hostname within a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, mariadb

If I set up MariaDB form the official image within a Docker Compose configuration, I can access it by its host name - for example if in a bash shell within the MariaDB container:

```
# host db
db has address 172.21.0.2


# curl telnet://db:3306
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

- no connection refused issue here

But if have MariaDB deployed from the official image within a Kubernetes cluster (tried both MicroK8s and GKE), I can connect to it via `localhost` but not by its host name:

```
# host db
db.my-namspace.svc.cluster.local has address 10.152.183.124

# curl telnet://db:3306
curl: (7) Failed to connect to db port 3306: Connection refused

# curl telnet://localhost:3306
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

- connection is refused for the service host name, but localhost responds

I've tried to replace the included `my.cnf` with a simplified version like:

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
skip-networking=0
#### Unix socket settings (making localhost work)
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

#### TCP Socket settings (making all remote logins work)
port         = 3306
bind-address = *
```

- with no luck

The MariaDB Kubernetes deployment is like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: db
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          value: template
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: root
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: template
        image: mariadb:10.4
        name: db
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          name: dbdata
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: dbdata
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: dbdata
status: {}
```

and the corresponding Persistent Volume Claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: dbdata
  name: dbdata
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
```

It baffles me that the same configuration works with Docker Compose but not within a Kubernetes cluster.

Any ideas what may be going on?

*Update 2020-03-18*
I forgot to include the service declaration for the database and add it here:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: db
  name: db
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "3306"
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: db
    name: db
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

...am including both `app` and `name` for the `spec.selector` - am used to having only `name` but @Al-waleed Shihadeh's example includes `app` so I'll include that also, just in case - but without success.

Here are outputs from a couple of kubectl listing commands:

```
$ sudo microk8s.kubectl get svc db -n my-namespace
NAME   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
db     ClusterIP   10.152.183.246   <none>        3306/TCP   35m
```

```
$ sudo microk8s.kubectl get pods -owide -n my-namespace
NAME                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
db-77cbcf87b6-l44lm            1/1     Running            0          34m   10.1.48.118   microk8s-vm   <none>           <none>
```

***Solution***
Comparing the service declaration posted by KoopaKiller, which proved to work, I finally noticed that setting the `protocol` attribute to "TCP" in the ports declaration was missing - this part:

```
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Kubernetes Deployment, the name of your pods will be generated dinamically based on the name you gave in spec file, in your example, the pods will be create with the name `db-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx`.

In order to make a 'fixed' hostname, you need to create a service for reach your pods, example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  selector:
    name: db
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  type: ClusterIP
```

And to check if was successfully deployed:

```
$ kubectl get svc db
NAME   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
db     ClusterIP   10.96.218.18   <none>        3306/TCP   89s
```

The fullname of your service will be: `<name>.<namespace>.cluster.local` in this case using `default` namespace will be `db.default.cluster.local` pointing to ip `10.96.218.18` as showed in example above.

To reach your service you need to configure your /etc/hosts with his information:

```
echo -ne "10.96.218.18\tdb.default.cluster.local db db.default" >> /etc/hosts
```

After that you will be able to reach your service by dns:

```
$ dig +short db
10.96.218.18

$ mysql -h db -uroot -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 5.5.5-10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Just for you know, you could also use HELM template to setup a mariadb with replication. See this [article](https://engineering.bitnami.com/articles/deploy-a-production-ready-mariadb-cluster-on-kubernetes-with-bitnami-and-helm.html)

**References:**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

Comment: I forgot to include my service declaration - have now updated the question with that.  As can be seen in the host command example, hostname `db` is declared and points to a local IP:  The problem is that connections to that host name or IP are refused on port 3306.  Please not that the examples shown are in a shell within the database container.

Comment: Your service resolution is pointing to `db.my-namspace.svc.cluster.local` but your yamls was not created in `my-namespace`. Could you please update the question with the outputs of the commands: `kubectl get svc -n default` and `kubectl get pods -n default -owide` ?

Comment: Your service IP doesn't match with the output of the command `host db` (10.152.183.124) in yout post. Check in your `/etc/hosts`, the line must be `10.152.183.246 db db.my-namespace.cluster.local`, is it correct ?

Comment: That's actually because I had recreated the container in the meantime, so the IPs from the `host` command in a shell within the container, and from `kubectl get svc ...` issued from outside the container, do in fact match, *but* /etc/hosts actually contains a different IP:  `10.1.48.118 db-77cbcf87b6-l44lm` *and* I can telnet to that IP.  How can that IP be different from the k8s svc cluster IP ?

Comment: You need to use the service ip, and not conteiner ip to connect, also, you are only point db-77cbcf87b6-l44l for this ip, it means you are not able to reach only `db`. Try to add in yout `/etc/hosts` this `10.152.183.246 db db.my-namespace.cluster.local` it will permit resolve `db` and `db.my-namespace.cluster.local` to service ip `10.152.183.246`.

Comment: That doesn't work, as the cluster IP results in connection refused on port 3306, while the container IP works.  I guess the main question here is, why doesn't the database accept connections on for the cluster IP?  The database is configured with `bind-address = *` which should set it to listen all interfaces, for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: I've tested here with the deployment yaml you posted, and with the service yaml in my answer and worked for me. Check if your service selector is matching the pod, based in your deployment yaml, selector in service must be `name: db`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209846/discussion-between-koopakiller-and-bjorn-thor-jonsson).

Comment: To summarise the findings from our chat:  The database service port declaration was missing the setting of the `protocol` attribute to `TCP`:   `spec.ports.protocol: TCP` was missing.

Answer (score 1):

to be able to access the service from the host node you need to define a service object in Kubernetes

so the complete k8s objects should look like the below snippet 
PersistentVolumeClaim

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: db-data
  name: db-data
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
```

Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mysql
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  type: ClusterIP
```

Deployment

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mysql
  name: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: dummy
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: community_db
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
            name: db-data
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
      volumes:
      - name: db-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: db-data
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Comment: I forgot to include my service declaration - have now updated the question with that.  As can be seen in the host command example, hostname `db` is declared and points to a local IP:  The problem is that connections to that host name or IP are refused on port 3306.  Please not that the examples shown are in a shell within the database container.

Answer (score 0):

Your root account, and this statement applies to any account, may only have been added with localhost access (which is recommended).

You can check this with:

```
SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'root';
```

If you only see results with localhost and 127.0.0.1, you cannot connect from an external source. If you see other IP addresses, but not the one you're connecting from - that's also an indication.

You will need to add the IP address of each system that you want to grant access to, and then grant privileges:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'ip_address' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'ip_address';
```

If you see %, well then, there's another problem altogether as that is "any remote source". If however you do want any/all systems to connect via root, use the % wildcard to grant access:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

Finally, reload the permissions, and you should be able to have remote access:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```